# I have a text file in the assets folder. How can I access a random sentence from that text file?

Tags: java, android

I have created inspiration text file in the assets folder. In that inspiration file, there are around 20 sentences. So how do I pick any one sentence randomly and display in text view. Now it is displaying all 20 sentences. Here is the code. Can any one please help me here.

```
tv_text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
String text = "";
try {
    InputStream is = getAssets().open("inspiration.txt");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    text = new String(buffer);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
tv_text1.setText(text);
```

Comment: how the sentence listed in inspiration.txt?

Comment: In separate line without the index.

Comment: read line by line using buffer reader. store it in a string array. -- using random() get the sentence.

Comment: 1) read the sentences from that file into list. 2) generate random integer in range 0..list length -1. 3) get the sentence from the list by generated index

Answer (score 2):

To read text from input stream:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("inspiration.txt");    
List<String> doc =
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource,
              StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Get Random String:

```
String randomSentence = doc.get((new Random()).nextInt(items.size()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
  reader = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("inspiration.txt")));

  // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
     String mLine;
     List<String> listLines  = new ArrayList<>();
     while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           //process line
           listLines.add(mLine);
     }

     if (listLines.size() > 0) {
         Random rand = new Random();
         int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(listLines.size());
         String randomLine = listLines.get(randomNumber);
         .......
     }

 } catch (IOException e) {
  //log the exception
 } finally {
   if (reader != null) {
      try {
         reader.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         //log the exception
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this, if the sentences are separated by a \n.
untested, you have to replace randomGenerator with something that gives you a random number between those two parameters. after the .split you have an array with all the lines of the text you loaded.

```
String splits[]=text.split('\n');
int random=randomGenerator(0,splits.length);
tv_text1.setText(splits[random]);
```

it's really more of a generic java question than an android question. is this an assignment?